# Setup Twitter Sign In and Get User Profile

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am new to this. I have read Twitter Documentation whole day but still clueless.

I need to setup a "Login with Twitter" button on my website, which login any random visitor and after that gets his profile info from Twitter.

I know it uses Oauth... and I guess... REST API also... but I don't see any examples related to PHP.

Any link to any tutorial would help!

Please, help! It is urgent!

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PHP Twitter library [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). There is [documentation](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION) that talks about how the example code works. The example code implements the Login With Twitter button, so you should be able to copy the code and use it on your site fairly easily.